# Ask about one issue regarding eigen library with raw buffer

Tags: c++, eigen

Recently I am using eigen library and I found this issue regarding raw buffer manipulation.

In the code below, I created two raw buffers of 9 integer as input and output. After that, I used two eigen matrices *in/out* to wrap these two buffers through placement new method with map of eigen. And then I invoked a simple transpose operation. However, different way to invoke transpose operation will lead to totally different raw buffer results. If I directly call the eigen transpose function like shown in code 1, the results are completely correct, both for the result matrix and corresponding raw buffer. But when I wrap the transpose operation in a customized function that returns a eigen matrix, like shown in code 2, the problem occurs. It turns out that only the result matrix is good but the raw buffer seems to be corrupted. Does some one know this issue? Is this a bug of eigen?

## Code 1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using Eigen::MatrixXi;                                                          


int main() {                                                                    
  int *in;                                                                      
  in = new int[9];                                                              
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)                                                   
    in[i] = i;                                                                  

  int *out;                                                                     
  out = new int[9];                                                             
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)                                                   
    out[i] = 0;                                                                 

  MatrixXi m_in;                                                                
  m_in.resize(3, 3);                                                            
  new (&m_in) Eigen::Map<MatrixXi>(in, 3, 3);                                   

  MatrixXi m_out;                                                               
  m_out.resize(3, 3);                                                           
  new (&m_out) Eigen::Map<MatrixXi>(out, 3, 3);                                 

  m_out = m_in.transpose();                                                     
  std::cout << m_out << std::endl;                                              
  std::cout << "------------" << std::endl;                                     
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)                                                   
    std::cout << out[i] << std::endl;                                           

  return 0;                                                                     
}
```

## Results of code 1:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
------------
0
3
6
1
4
7
2
5
8
```

## Code 2

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using Eigen::MatrixXi;                                                          

MatrixXi MyTranspose(const MatrixXi &in) {                                      
  return in.transpose();                                                        
}                                                                               

int main() {                                                                    
  int *in;                                                                      
  in = new int[9];                                                              
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)                                                   
    in[i] = i;                                                                  

  int *out;                                                                     
  out = new int[9];                                                             
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)                                                   
    out[i] = 0;                                                                 

  MatrixXi m_in;                                                                
  m_in.resize(3, 3);                                                            
  new (&m_in) Eigen::Map<MatrixXi>(in, 3, 3);                                   

  MatrixXi m_out;                                                               
  m_out.resize(3, 3);                                                           
  new (&m_out) Eigen::Map<MatrixXi>(out, 3, 3);                                 

  m_out = MyTranspose(m_in);                                                     
  std::cout << m_out << std::endl;                                              
  std::cout << "------------" << std::endl;                                     
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)                                                   
    std::cout << out[i] << std::endl;                                           

  return 0;                                                                     
}
```

## Results of code 2:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
------------
1028430744
32644
1028430744
32644
0
0
0
0
48
```

Comment: Why are you using placement new? It will overwrite the local objects `m_in` and `m_out` with a different type? One has heap allocated data and the other is local on the stack. UB.  Just do them this way ` Eigen::Map<MatrixXi> m_in(in, 3, 3);`

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting one object with another of a differing type. `m_in` is being overwritten by the contents of `Eigen::Map<MatrixXi>(in, 3, 3)` since it is the target of the placement new. `m_in` is not the owner of the `in` buffer and later operations assuming it is will corrupt the heap.

```
MatrixXi m_in;                                                                
m_in.resize(3, 3);                                                            
new (&m_in) Eigen::Map<MatrixXi>(in, 3, 3);
```

Replace these 3 lines (and the similar lines for m_out) by:

```
Eigen::Map<MatrixXi> m_in(in, 3, 3);
```

This will not allocate any additional memory from the heap but utilize previously allocated `in[]` and `out[]`.

Another problem is that `in[]` and `out[]` are not deleted. It doesn't matter since the program is exiting anyway but memory leak prone programming style should be discouraged.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Just one question regarding your answer. Why the argument will be copied when const ref is used? Isn't argument copy supposed to be avoided through the usage of reference?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Initially I was thinking that `m_in.transpose()` was modifying m_in in place and would have had to make a copy of it. It is not. The transpose() method doesn't modify the data but returns a different type that causes subsequent access to treat the data permuted to effect a transpose operation .So a const & is the right way to call it. I'll edit that part of the answer.